# While draging image in Unity 2D, it is moved only minimally even with large mouse movements

Tags: unity-game-engine, drag

I have written the following code to move 2D images around on a scroll view. It works, but they only move minimally. If I drag with the mouse over the whole screen, the image only moves a little bit. Why is that?

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class DraggableObject : MonoBehaviour, IPointerDownHandler, IPointerUpHandler
{
    private bool isDragging = false;
    private Vector3 offset;
    private SceneController sceneController;
    [SerializeField] GameObject ObjectToDrag;
    [SerializeField] private BoxCollider boxCollider;
    [SerializeField] private Image image;

    void Start()
    {
        sceneController = GameObject.Find("Controller").GetComponent<SceneController>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (isDragging)
        {
            ObjectToDrag.transform.position = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition) + offset;
        }
    }

    public void SetSizeOfBoxCollider()
    {
        RectTransform rectTransform = image.rectTransform;
        float width = rectTransform.rect.width;
        float height = rectTransform.rect.height;
        Vector3 sizeAsVector3 = new Vector3(width, height, 0);

        boxCollider.size = sizeAsVector3;

    }

    public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        isDragging = true;
        offset = ObjectToDrag.transform.position - Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        sceneController.DeactivateScrollView();
    }

    public void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        isDragging = false;
        sceneController.ActivateScrollView();
    }
}
```

Comment: what happens if you dont do the offset

Comment: If I remove the offset, it is simply moved to some coordinates so that it is no longer visible.

Comment: I just had Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition) output the values and that seems to be the problem. Why do I get such small values and not the "real" values that my mouse moves over the screen?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem. I simply had to

```
Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition)
```

replace it with

```
Input.mousePosition
```